# What is the difference between using `chunckHash` and using hash in HTMLWebpackPlugin?

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, caching, hash

I am currently trying to hash my javascript file. I was trying, unscssfully, to use chunckHash. I have now noticed HTMLWebpackPlugin allows me to hash a file and pass that file through to the HTML script tag, which is ideal. However, am I missing anything by not using chunckHash?

Comment: I understand my answer is kind of abstract but since there's no code I can only apply theory here to answer. Hope it helps understanding the difference between the `hash` of the bundle and different `chunks` you can manage with the code splitting method

Answer (score 0):

`chunkhash` is part of the code splitting method to reduce the main bundle and split sources into multiple small files.

**The difference** is you can prefix or suffix your chunks just like you would do it with `hash` but export them applying different filters or conditions for different paths/folders

```
/* Soucre: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputchunkfilename */
output: {
    chunkFilename: (pathData) => {
      return pathData.chunk.name === 'main' ? '[name].js' : '[name]/[name].js';
    },
}
```

Source chunkHash: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/

Source for code splitting method: https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/

Comment: When I use the HTMLWebPlugin it add the hash at the end of the js file so bundle.js?<hash>. All I need it for is to get around CloudFront cacheing and not updating between deployments for an hour or so. So if a use the plugin, the only difference is not being able to choose where the hash goes?

Comment: `hash` is used to force the cache to update the new bundle version, it's an identifier of the version of the build. `chunkHash` is used when you turn your bundle into multiple files (aka chunks, from code splitting), The only point of `chunkHash` is to manage the chunks, but if you don't do code splitting, there's no point on using it since the only chunk you'll have is the main one

Comment: Here's a visual representation between bundling (left) and code splitting (right)
`https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*3PIRkDZR8rlwRa7S_pb1Ng.png`

Comment: Awesome, no, I am using one bundle file that is then pushed to s3. 
So say I have `filename: bundle.[hash].js` how would I update my index.html dynamically to get the hashed bundle file? At the moment I am using `HTMLWebPlugin` but if there is a way of doing it without installing this plug in I'd be interested.




  `plugins: [ new HTMLWebpackPlugin({ template: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.html',), hash: true}),`


<< How I currently hash and update the index.html file.

Comment: The reason you use `'src', 'index.html'` is to update the index.html file by adding the sources with hash to the file. You are supposed to upload that generated file when you change your sources. What you are trying to achieve is a very diffrent question. You can redirect everything with `main.*.js` in the server to the target `main.js`, or make your own versionning system but you'll still need to update and upload the `index.html` file to the server since that's the file that loads your bundle

Comment: Yes I understand the `src, index.html` section. It is adding the hashed bundle.js filename to a script tag it creates in the file. My question is, can this be done another way. So not using this plugin?

Comment: Please open a new question asking this specific question. This question is about `What is the difference between using 'chunckHash' and using hash in HTMLWebpackPlugin?`